# Why doesn't 12.10 give me an option to Install beside windows 7?

Tags: installation, 12.10

I burned the image to a dvd and I get to the install screen but it doesn't ask me about installing beside windows.  My only choices are to delete windows and loose everything or "Something Else".

Any suggestions?

Comment: This may be because Windows has taken up all 4 primary partitions. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

While Installation choose **"Something else"** and setup your partitions manually:

and follow

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5Jxfj6tu_U
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ

check out tutorial on how to install dual boot system
[How to install Side by Side Boot on Windows XP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204928/how-to-install-side-by-side-boot-on-windows-xp/205230#205230)

Answer (score 0):

Yes-go for this manuals

- http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ

it s usefull cause by defalt ubuntu take all hard space you have but dedicated /home gives you an opportunity to reinstall ubuntu without having to delete files everytime

Answer (score 0):

This can happen sometimes and I also experienced it before. *(I have a bad habit of reinstalling every 2-3 months)*. This happens because Ubuntu installer couldn't find a good way to give you an option for install beside Windows. ***But, that doesn't mean you can't install Ubuntu retaining Windows***.

Select **Something else** and try using manual partitioning. I suggest to resize a big partition first to create some free space. And then creating two partition in that free space. Use one for `/` and another for swap space.

Take a look at these pages for more help.

- [Windows Dual Boot - Community Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Manual_partitioning)
- [Manual disk partitioning guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/)