# starts installing then hangs

Tags: system-installation

I used both ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 the live cd runs great but when I go to install either one it starts installing then hangs, not sure whats going on but i let it sit over night even and still was on black screen showing ubuntu mouse curser in motion..  but like I said it runs great on live cd, I'm able to use the internet and everything else but it hangs while installing.  I'm using a clean hard drive with nothing on it..  is there something Im missing?
I tried using usb stick install a

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to boot from live dvd or any device with ubuntu system and re-manage hard drive with gparted application ,as you have clean hard drive try to format it and check for some **erorrs**

- [How can I check my RAM and hard drive for errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14303/how-can-i-check-my-ram-and-harddrive-for-errors)

use tutorial to create partitions from here 
[How to install Side by Side Boot on Windows XP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204928/how-to-install-side-by-side-boot-on-windows-xp/205230#205230)
or just create partitions like shown in this video its russian but you dont have to understand words just see guy clicking and do

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Wryt1adY9E