# how to install ubuntu? step by step procedure from usb stick

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)

I want a detailed step by step procedure for installing ubuntu 12.04 from a usb stick.
i have downloaded the iso file and installed ubuntu in a usb.now i want to install it completly in my system erasing the previous operating system.i want a detailed procedure for that.

Comment: can anyone tell me how to do it or suggest any link?thanks in advance!

Comment: @RickGreen This is a duplicate of so very many questions. This question is a staple: it gets asked so much, that it's not even worth flagging anymore. The people that ask these kinds of questions don't seem to know how to do research on their own, so what we need to do is answer their question promptly and thoroughly, and then get ready to answer the next repetition of it, (which usually occurs as soon as the last one leaves the front page. Search boxes are _highly_ difficult to use after all.) Is this question a duplicate? Yes, more like a triplicate or centeplicate. We still provide answers.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Thanks so much for bringing me into light....I couldn't find my way with both hands and headlights of Boeing 777. I can understand how difficult it may be for some to use those pesky search boxes so lets not even try to steer those folks in the right direction. The next time a new member with less than 10 reps ask I know what to do......CLOSED! PERIOD! End of statement.

Comment: @RickGreen Actually, I help them. (I actually take it as a challenge to try to answer it before it gets reported and closed.) So far, I've answered that question 3 times. ([1](http://askubuntu.com/a/217211/95681) [2](http://askubuntu.com/a/226686/95681) [3](http://askubuntu.com/a/204960/95681)) If somebody needs help on a problem, I don't refuse to help just because they're stupid. I actually answer their question. (also it's a great way to grind for reputation. It's a con where everyone wins: Stupid People get their Ubuntu, the Moderators get their Closed Question, and I get my Reputation. ;)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude   What should happen is we should keep a arsenal of "pat" answers handy.....then BOOM. There ya go.

Comment: @RickGreen Lol, yeah, I probably should do that. There's a User Script that has "canned comments," now I just need one with "canned answers!" XD I've lost many a Reputation because the moderators were just too fast... ;(

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude This approach is entirely wrong. Racing against close-voters to answer a question that you yourself think merits closure is not using the site correctly. Throwing fragments of knowledge at people while isolating them from each other does not help anyone. It's fine to answer questions with close-votes when you think the close votes may be wrong, but when you find a duplicate, you should comment, refer the OP to the master question, and if you have a good answer, *post it there*.

Comment: @EliahKagan You know, I think it's time for a haiku, to help clarify the situation: *They want to close it. I have the knowledge to help. The battle begins.* **JUST KIDDING.** However, if someone was too lazy to use the search feature, closing a question isn't going to help a thing. If they couldn't be bothere d to search first, what makes you think they'll click on the Duplicate link?

Comment: OOH! Bonus points for answering a question, *THEN FLAGGING THE QUESTION!* Boo yah! EVERYbody wins!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you may want to print this.

1. Make the live USB. *(sounds like you already did this part)*
2. Put the USB stick into your computer, then reboot it.
3. During the boot-up, while the BIOS is loading (usually it will show the logo of the company who made your computer,) spam all the F# keys (usually it's F12) so that it will ask you where you want to boot from. (If it enters a settings menu, reboot and try again. You want to get into the "boot select" menu or something like that.)
4. Pick "USB" (NOTE: if this option isn't available, you may have to go with a CD...)
5. If you've done everything correctly, it will display this logo that looks like "[stick figure]
6. Follow the on-screen instructions to install Ubuntu!

If you need any more help, just ask me in a comment. (Use another computer for that.) I will be glad to provide assistance.

Comment: thanky you! that was useful.i thought we must do the patitions,but there no need for that. ubuntu 12.04LTS got installed in my system!

Comment: Yeah, it's really handy that the installer can automatically partition your disk for you, should you decide to have a dual-boot. *If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.*

Answer (score 0):

**Windows:**

Learn more at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

**Mac Os X:**

1
Download Ubuntu Desktop

2
Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight).

3
Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil (e.g.,hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso)

Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.

4
Run diskutil list to get the current list of devices.

5
Insert your flash media.

6
Run diskutil list again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. /dev/disk2).

7
Run diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2).

8
Execute sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m (replace /path/to/downloaded.img with the path where the image file is located; for example, ./ubuntu.imgor ./ubuntu.dmg).

Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster
If you see the error dd: Invalid number '1m', you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace bs=1m with bs=1M
If you see the error dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the 'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive
9
Run diskutil eject /dev/diskN and remove your flash media when the command completes.

10
Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

Learn more at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

**Ubuntu:**

1
Insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space.

2
Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator.

3
Select the Startup Disk Creator to launch the app.

4
Click 'Other' to choose the downloaded ISO file.

5
Select the file and click 'Open'.

6
Select the USB stick in the bottom box and click 'Make Startup Disk'.

7
That's it! When the process completes, you'll be ready to restart your computer and begin installing Ubuntu.

Learn more in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

If your computer doesn’t automatically bring the boot menu, you might need to press the F12 key(or Esc Key) to bring up the boot menu, but be careful not to hold it down - that can cause an error message.

1
Turn on your computer with the usb already pluged in

2
Then quickly press esc or F12 to bring the boot menu.

3
Choose the Usb option and then you do the waint part.

4
Then it's easy just configurate the ubuntu and you're ready.

Comment: i have done exactly the same.i wold like to know the installation on the system.i.e we get two options.1.try ubuntu 2.install ubuntu.then how do we do the partitions...etc.