# Reinstall an Ubuntu OS?

Tags: grub2

I installed a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows 7 and my Ubuntu OS got corrupted, somehow over time I added 2 more Ubuntu OS's. I understand I'm a complete idiot and shouldn't have played around, but I looked it up on Google and they said I could delete the partitions, so I tried. Now my computer gives me a Grub Error, I tried my own obvious: I got my installation USB's for Ubuntu and tried to boot from them, but I got a Grub Error again on one USB and on my second USB I got a blank command prompt where i couldn't type anything.

I don't care to get the data back, but I would like to be able to use it. I don't care to recover any of my files for either Windows 7 or Ubuntu. I only care to get my computer back.

Comment: Do you want install ubuntu alone or keep dual boot ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you may have deleted partitions on your USB devices, meaning they no longer contain any Ubuntu to boot from. I'd start by recreating them as you did originally.

Answer (score 0):

## FIRST,

**consider using the Live CD/USB to back up your files to an external hard drive.**

After you've either done that or decided not to, here's how to install Ubuntu over your entire computer:

1. Boot from the CD/USB, just like you did the first time you installed.
2. Choose "Install Ubuntu," along with your language (I'm assuming it's English.)
3. Tell Ubuntu to "Erase everything and reinstall."
4. While it's installing, set up your computer. (Time zone, username/password, etc.)
5. Reboot at the prompt.
6. Enjoy your fresh installation of Ubuntu. You're done!

If you have any questions, see the [official documentation on how to install Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall).

One last thing: I always wondered about this, but I finally got my answer when I had to reinstall Ubuntu several times (long story...)
Install from CD takes an hour or so; Live USB installs in minutes. **Go with USB if possible.**