# How to change the SATA Mode from AHCI to IDE to install Windows XP for dual boot? (Ubuntu installed first)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

Good day guys, I just installed ubuntu and it replaced my current OS Windows 7 Ultimate. Now I want to go back to windows and try to install XP but now I'm unable to install ANY VERSION OF WINDOWS because others says that it requires IDE as controller. Unfortunately, I can't change it in BIOS at startup.Please help guys :(

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204928/how-to-install-side-by-side-boot-on-windows-xp?rq=1

Comment: There are custom builds of WinXP which support SATA chips. Just check via torrents.

Comment: It is unclear what your issue is. XP needs an IDE controller, but not Ubuntu. Some older BIOS may not support this. Anyway, it appears that this is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Virusboy I don't think this is what he wants.

Comment: I agree with @Takkat completely. You did not give us enough information about your computer and what your problem is. BIOS version doesn't really help here. Thanks for trying. Please take this over to Super User where they will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried out Ubuntu, and you found it's not your cup of tea, great. However, I would not recommend installing Windows XP, as it is no longer supported by Microsoft as of April 8. I would suggest either A) just go back to Windows 7 or B) try out another Linux distro, such as Xubuntu. There are plenty of options to choose from.

However, if you *really* want to install Windows XP, AFAIK there is no way in software to change the BIOS. Here are my suggestions:

1. Make sure you know what button to press when your computer starts up (some common ones are <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd>, and <kbd>Del</kbd>)
2. Check your BIOS settings again. You may have missed something if you actually *have* looked in there.
3. Like I said before, just don't try installing XP. I honestly don't think it's worth it.

**EDIT:** I guess this is not what you wanted. I'm going to try again.

Here are my suggestions if your computer won't let you install Windows at all:

1. Burn a GParted CD on one of your computers--whichever one works at the moment.
2. Boot to the GParted CD and create a new partition table on your disk. You probably want to create a Master Boot Record partition table, seeing as you originally had Windows 7. If your computer actually has UEFI (which is a possibility), use a GUID partition table instead.
3. If installing Windows still doesn't work, try booting into GParted again and creating an NTFS partition on your hard drive.
4. If all else fails, bring this up on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). There should be people there who know more about your problem. This is clearly not an Ubuntu related issue, except for the fact that you want to switch back to Windows from Ubuntu. This is as far as I will help you here.

Comment: Sir/Ma'am the problem is when i try Windows 7, 8 or 8.1 I got \Boot\BCD error and I can't proceed to click install and choose language etc... But when I try it on my other PC it worked perfectly I just don't know why can't I reinstall any Windows Version on my computer.

Comment: @thefourthXian look at my edit and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want XP for some things, but want to retain ubuntu, you could install a virtual machine in ubuntu and run xp from there.  Either vmware or virtualbox would work.